# Is there a way to change tab bar style in component rather then App.js?

Tags: react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

My app support English and Arabic with LTR and RTL support.

I am using BottomTabBarNavigation `createBottomTabNavigator` for tab menu and it works fine.

I have following styles setup for tab menu.

```
tabBarOptions: {
  labelStyle: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  activeTintColor: '#fdb64b',
  inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  style: {
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(10),
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    height: moderateScale(50),
    paddingTop: moderateScale(9),
    borderTopColor: '#191919',
    borderTopWidth: moderateScale(1)
  }
}
```

In the above style, If I add `flexDirection: 'row'` or `flexDirection: 'row-reverse'` it gives me the desired style of flipping the direction of tab menu.

What I am trying to achieve is, I have a change language screen, I want the tab bar to apply the style of `'row-reverse'` if Arabic is selected and `'row'` when English is selected.

With something like this in tabBarOptions

```
flexDirection: global.IS_RTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row'
```

The problem is I cannot do it in App.js, I want to do it in one of the component when the application is loaded, is there any way to acheive this in react-native?

Thanks

Comment: you have to create custom tab [CustomTabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133227/passing-props-to-a-dynamic-tabnavigator)

Comment: Sounds interesting, will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion and experience, I will recommend using (native-base) Tab bar. It is easier than others and can be edited easily in the component. You can open it from (react-native base doc).